# Number of ways to arrange $5$ a and $5$ b letter

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Lets say you have  $5$ items of a and $5$ items of b.

There are $10$ open spots. How many different ways can we order can we order those items? So for example..

> a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b

is one combination.

---

I would appreciate if anyone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is what is called Counting in Partitions. In general, if there are $n$ items and there are $k$ partitions each consisting of $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$ items such that $n_1+n_2+\dots+n_k=n$, then the number of ways that you can order the $n$ items is given by the "Multinomial" coefficient ${n \choose n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k}=\frac{n!}{n_1! \space n_2! \space \dots \space n_k!}$.

Comment: There exists $\frac{10!}{5!5!}=252$ configurations

Comment: We need to **choose** the $5$ places where the a's will go.

Comment: As Andre says, how many places can the first 'a' go?  The second? ... The fifth?  But the 'a's are indistinguishable, so for each pattern we've produced, how many times did we create it by placing the 'a's in a different order?  The end result will be what Adi wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrange 5 a's and 5 b's, you'd have to choose 5 out of 10 spots to position the a's.
The b's naturally occupy the remaining positions.

So the number of ways to arrange them is C(5,10), which is 252.